# How can I sum an int with a list? TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python, list, function, definition

First of all, I am a fresh student to python, so this might be easy, but I tried my best to research before asking here. Anyway, If I change "for tall in minListe" with " for minListe in [5, 2, -4, 2, -1, 0, 2, -2, 3, 0, 7]" it works, but that's not good enough... Anyone knows how to do this without having to include my list within the function?

```
total = 0

tall = 0

minListe = [5, 2, -4, 2, -1, 0, 2, -2, 3, 0, 7]

def funksjon2(total):

    total = 0 
    for tall in minListe:
        if minListe == 0:
            break
        total = total + minListe
    return (total)

def main():

    print(funksjon2(total))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(

)
```

Comment: You can pass the list to the function as an argument. `total` is not making any sense here as an argument because you are defining `total=0` in the function anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your logic correctly, you are trying to do the following. Try the below code and drop a comment below if it works or not. I have added some comments where I have modified things

```
minListe = [5, 2, -4, 2, -1, 0, 2, -2, 3, 0, 7]

def funksjon2(minListe):
    total = 0
    for tall in minListe:
        if tall == 0: # Replaced minListe by tall
            break
        total = total + tall # # Replaced minListe by tall
    return (total)

print(funksjon2(minListe))

> 4 # Answer
```

Comment: Great. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a list to an int, so intuitively this won't work. Your error is in the line:

```
if minListe == 0:
    total = total + minListe
```

Instead, this should be

```
if tall == 0:
    total = total + tall
    # or 'total += tall'
```

Because `tall` is an int in `minListe` whereas as `minListe` is the list itself.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:
total = 0 
    for tall in minListe:
        if minListe == 0:
            break
        total = total + tall
    return (total)

you should not add the list with the int. Just add the tall iterator to your total.